# xcode: annotation to map

Tags: xcode, dictionary, annotations

my app is showing the map in the right way, but the annotation (the pin of a place choosen by me) isn't displayed... why?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
zoomLocation.latitude = 45.40170;
zoomLocation.longitude = 8.91552;
MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, METERS_PER_MILE, METERS_PER_MILE);
[_mappa setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];
[_mappa regionThatFits:viewRegion];
MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
point.coordinate = zoomLocation;
point.title = @"TITLE";
point.subtitle = @"SUBTITLE";
[_mappa addAnnotation:point];
}
```

sorry but i'm new to xcode, for smartphone, i've developed only on android

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to add the annotation to the MKMapView correctly, but you need to provide an annotation view for the annotation by implementing delegate method mapView: viewForAnnotation: in your view controller, like this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

static NSString *identifier = @"MyLocation";

    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [_mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    } else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    annotationView.enabled = YES;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

    return annotationView;
}
```

Assuming you're using interface builder, make sure you set the MKMapView's delegate to your view controller.

Comment: I don't have clear the last part:
Assuming you're using interface builder, make sure you set the MKMapView's delegate to your view controller.
Yes i am using the xib

Comment: @DFerra When your xib is open, make sure that if you select the MKMapView inside your view and look at the Connections inspector, that the "delegate" outlet is set.  If not, Control+click on it, drag over to the File's Owner placeholder to connect it.  If this isn't done mapView:annotationForView: will never fire.

Comment: i did it all, it doesn't change anything.
i've inserted your code (changing [_mapView to [_mappa because of the name), linked the owner, but nothing appeared

Comment: hmmm...not sure what to try next.  If you post your XCode project on github or something like that, I'd be happy to download and try debugging it that way.

Comment: @DFerra Or, you can check out my test project where I got it to drop two annotation points here: https://github.com/keithkurak/ClevelandBikeMap (ignore the MKPolyline stuff).  I was trying to do the same thing just a few days ago- my tips so far was what got it working for me, but maybe there's something else missing in there.